# primefaces dialog Model didn't show any value

Tags: jsf, dialog, primefaces

I'm using primefaces dialog model to show more details upon clicking a button.but i'm unable to get the value on the dialog box.

```
   <p:dataGrid id ="boardpanel" var="item" value="#{bLDashBoardAction.listBondLoc}" columns="#{message.no_of_columns}"  
    rows="20" paginator="true">  

    <p:column>  
        <p:panel header="Details" style="text-align:center">  
            <h:panelGrid columns="1" style="width:100%;">  


         <h:outputText value="#{item.rackTagCode}"  title="#{item.rackTagCode}" /> 

                <p:commandLink update=":frmDashBoard:blDetail" oncomplete="blDialog.show()" title="View Detail">  
                    <p:graphicImage value="/images/search.png"/>   
                    ***<f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{item}" 
                            target="#{bLDashBoardAction.rackTagCode}" />***  
                </p:commandLink>  
            </h:panelGrid>  
        </p:panel>  
    </p:column>  

</p:dataGrid>  

<p:dialog header="BL Detail" widgetVar="blDialog" modal="true">
  <p:outputPanel id="blDetail" style="text-align:center;" layout="block">
 <h:panelGrid  columns="2" cellpadding="2">
    <h:outputLabel for="blNo" value="BL " />
        ***<h:outputText id="blNo" value="#{item.rackTagCode}" />*** 

</h:panelGrid>
```

I'm getting list of rackTagCode from getListBondLoc function in BLDashBoardAction class.
This is my getListBondLoc Function:

```
private String  bondLocationId;
private String  serviceAreaId;
private String facilityId;
private String bondLocationCode;
private String awb;
private String  zoneId;
private String  sectorId;
private String rackTagCode;
private String blTagCode;
private String ipAddress;
private String  ptlStatusId;
private String errorCode;
private String processIndicator;
private String textMsg;
private String rackTagCodeSel;
private BondLocationEBean beanSel;

private List<BondLocationEBean> listBondLoc;

public String navigateList(){
    listBondLoc = bondLocBusServ.searchBondLocList();
    return "/jsp/dashboard/dashboard";
}

public void doSearch()
{

    listBondLoc = bondLocBusServ.searchBondLocList(sectorId, zoneId, facilityId,ptlStatusId);
}
```

the remaining codes are getters & setters of above attributes where BondLocationEBean is mapped to all the columns in db.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally found the solution,

```
<f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{item}" 
                        target="#{bLDashBoardAction.blEbean}" />
```

i should point an Ebean object as target,then i would able to get the variables with bLDashBoardAction.blEbean.rackTagCode.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the wrong type of variable in your dialog box. Change

`<h:outputText id="blNo" value="#{item.rackTagCode}" />`

to

```
<h:outputText id="blNo" value="#{bLDashBoardAction.rackTagCode}" />
```

Comment: hi thanks for your answer.but i got like this in dialog box:

persistence.bean.BondLocationEBean@1d60b6a ,do i need to convert anything ?

Comment: in your `<f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{item}" target="#{bLDashBoardAction.rackTagCode}"/>` set the value to `#{item.rackTagCode}` that might solve the issue

Comment: after i changed like above,it didn't print anything

Comment: what is the name of your class?

Comment: name of ActionClass where i get the list :BLDashBoardACtion,
Ebean Class name- BondLocationEBean